# Group data by date time field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure

```
| id                  | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
| unique_id           | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |
| date_time           | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |
| float_value_1       | float    | NO   |     | 0       |
| float_value_2       | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

The data stored in this table represents a timeseries data with 5 minutes interval.

I am trying to figure out a MySQL query to aggregate the float values by grouping using unique_id and date_time into 15 minutes interval values, 1 hr interval values, and 1 day interval values.

I tried the following to aggregate the values into 1 hr intervals for a given unique_id but seems I got the aggregation/grouping concept incorrectly

```
select sum(float_value_1), sum(float_value_2), date_time*12 from location_data where unique_id = 1616 group by HOUR(date_time), day(date_time),  month(date_time) , year(date_time) ;
```

I am trying to figure out how to write the queries correctly for each interval (15 minutes, 1 hr, and 1 day)

Thanks in Advance!

[edit]
Data would look like this

```
   +----------+-------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
    | id       | unique_id | date_time  | float_value_1 | created_at          | updated_at          | float_value_2  |
    +----------+-------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
    | 27759971 |        1569 | 1410593400 |             37.7907 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |       NULL |
    | 27759972 |        1569 | 1410593700 |             38.9535 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    13.9535 |
    | 27759973 |        1569 | 1410594000 |             54.0698 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    181.395 |
    | 27759974 |        1569 | 1410594300 |             104.651 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    606.977 |
    | 27759975 |        1569 | 1410594600 |             98.2558 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -76.7442 |
    | 27759976 |        1569 | 1410594900 |             61.6279 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -439.535 |
    | 27759977 |        1569 | 1410595200 |             83.7209 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    265.116 |
    | 27759978 |        1569 | 1410595500 |             110.465 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |     320.93 |
    | 27759979 |        1569 | 1410595800 |             135.465 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |        300 |
    | 27759980 |        1569 | 1410596100 |             193.023 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    690.698 |
    | 27759981 |        1569 | 1410596400 |             206.977 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    167.442 |
    | 27759982 |        1569 | 1410596700 |             251.163 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    530.233 |
    | 27759983 |        1569 | 1410597000 |             338.372 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1046.51 |
    | 27759984 |        1569 | 1410597300 |              504.07 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1988.37 |
    | 27759985 |        1569 | 1410597600 |             503.488 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -6.97674 |
    | 27759986 |        1569 | 1410597900 |             333.721 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -2037.21 |
    | 27759987 |        1569 | 1410598200 |             284.884 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -586.047 |
    | 27759988 |        1569 | 1410598500 |             227.326 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -690.698 |
    | 27759989 |        1569 | 1410598800 |             218.605 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -104.651 |
    | 27759990 |        1569 | 1410599100 |             232.558 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    167.442 |
    | 27759991 |        1569 | 1410599400 |             293.605 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    732.558 |
    | 27759992 |        1569 | 1410599700 |             305.233 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    139.535 |
    | 27759993 |        1569 | 1410600000 |             303.488 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -20.9302 |
    | 27759994 |        1569 | 1410600300 |             258.721 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -537.209 |
    | 27759995 |        1569 | 1410600600 |             237.209 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    -258.14 |
    | 27759996 |        1569 | 1410600900 |             368.023 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1569.77 |
    | 27759997 |        1569 | 1410601200 |             459.884 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1102.33 |
    | 27759998 |        1569 | 1410601500 |             598.837 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1667.44 |
    | 27759999 |        1569 | 1410601800 |              691.86 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1116.28 |
    | 27760000 |        1569 | 1410602100 |             555.814 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -1632.56 |
    | 27760001 |        1569 | 1410602400 |             482.558 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    -879.07 |
    | 27760002 |        1569 | 1410602700 |             469.186 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -160.465 |
    | 27760003 |        1569 | 1410603000 |             450.581 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -223.256 |
    | 27760004 |        1569 | 1410603300 |             374.419 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -913.953 |
    | 27760005 |        1569 | 1410603600 |             338.372 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -432.558 |
    | 27760006 |        1569 | 1410603900 |             352.907 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    174.419 |
    | 27760007 |        1569 | 1410604200 |             359.884 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    83.7209 |
    | 27760008 |        1569 | 1410604500 |             398.256 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    460.465 |
    | 27760009 |        1569 | 1410604800 |             442.442 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    530.233 |
    | 27760010 |        1569 | 1410605100 |             418.605 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -286.047 |
    | 27760011 |        1569 | 1410605400 |             368.605 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |       -600 |
    | 27760012 |        1569 | 1410605700 |             370.349 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    20.9302 |
    | 27760013 |        1569 | 1410606000 |             468.605 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1179.07 |
    | 27760014 |        1569 | 1410606300 |             628.488 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |     1918.6 |
    | 27760015 |        1569 | 1410606600 |             508.721 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -1437.21 |
    | 27760016 |        1569 | 1410606900 |             397.093 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -1339.53 |
    | 27760017 |        1569 | 1410607200 |             481.977 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |     1018.6 |
    | 27760018 |        1569 | 1410607500 |             451.163 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -369.767 |
    | 27760019 |        1569 | 1410607800 |             454.651 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    41.8605 |
    | 27760020 |        1569 | 1410608100 |             595.349 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1688.37 |
    | 27760021 |        1569 | 1410608400 |             744.767 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1793.02 |
    | 27760022 |        1569 | 1410608700 |             660.465 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -1011.63 |
    | 27760023 |        1569 | 1410609000 |             454.651 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -2469.77 |
    | 27760024 |        1569 | 1410609300 |             387.791 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -802.326 |
    | 27760025 |        1569 | 1410609600 |             349.419 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -460.465 |
    | 27760026 |        1569 | 1410609900 |             466.279 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1402.33 |
    | 27760027 |        1569 | 1410610200 |             478.488 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    146.512 |
    | 27760028 |        1569 | 1410610500 |             412.209 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -795.349 |
    | 27760029 |        1569 | 1410610800 |             350.581 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -739.535 |
    | 27760030 |        1569 | 1410611100 |             322.674 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -334.884 |
    | 27760031 |        1569 | 1410611400 |             426.744 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1248.84 |
    | 27760032 |        1569 | 1410611700 |             487.791 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    732.558 |
    | 27760033 |        1569 | 1410612000 |             472.093 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -188.372 |
    | 27760034 |        1569 | 1410612300 |             391.279 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -969.767 |
    | 27760035 |        1569 | 1410612600 |             352.326 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -467.442 |
    | 27760036 |        1569 | 1410612900 |             384.884 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    390.698 |
    | 27760037 |        1569 | 1410613200 |             397.674 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    153.488 |
    | 27760038 |        1569 | 1410613500 |              345.93 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    -620.93 |
    | 27760039 |        1569 | 1410613800 |             258.721 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -1046.51 |
    | 27760040 |        1569 | 1410614100 |             183.721 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |       -900 |
    | 27760041 |        1569 | 1410614400 |              170.93 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -153.488 |
    | 27760042 |        1569 | 1410614700 |             259.884 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1067.44 |
    | 27760043 |        1569 | 1410615000 |             381.395 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1458.14 |
    | 27760044 |        1569 | 1410615300 |              266.86 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -1374.42 |
    | 27760045 |        1569 | 1410615600 |             194.767 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -865.116 |
    | 27760046 |        1569 | 1410615900 |             261.047 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    795.349 |
    | 27760047 |        1569 | 1410616200 |              291.86 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    369.767 |
    | 27760048 |        1569 | 1410616500 |              304.07 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    146.512 |
    | 27760049 |        1569 | 1410616800 |             286.628 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -209.302 |
    | 27760050 |        1569 | 1410617100 |             279.651 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -83.7209 |
    | 27760051 |        1569 | 1410617400 |             283.721 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    48.8372 |
    | 27760052 |        1569 | 1410617700 |             414.535 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1569.77 |
    | 27760053 |        1569 | 1410618000 |             613.953 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    2393.02 |
    | 27760054 |        1569 | 1410618300 |              545.93 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -816.279 |
    | 27760055 |        1569 | 1410618600 |             522.093 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -286.047 |
    | 27760056 |        1569 | 1410618900 |             417.442 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -1255.81 |
    | 27760057 |        1569 | 1410619200 |             323.837 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -1123.26 |
    | 27760058 |        1569 | 1410619500 |             401.744 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    934.884 |
    | 27760059 |        1569 | 1410619800 |             387.791 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -167.442 |
    | 27760060 |        1569 | 1410620100 |             376.163 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -139.535 |
    | 27760061 |        1569 | 1410620400 |             445.349 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    830.233 |
    | 27760062 |        1569 | 1410620700 |             431.395 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -167.442 |
    | 27760063 |        1569 | 1410621000 |             434.302 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    34.8837 |
    | 27760064 |        1569 | 1410621300 |             547.093 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1353.49 |
    | 27760065 |        1569 | 1410621600 |             557.558 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    125.581 |
    | 27760066 |        1569 | 1410621900 |             484.302 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    -879.07 |
    | 27760067 |        1569 | 1410622200 |             482.558 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -20.9302 |
    | 27760068 |        1569 | 1410622500 |             675.581 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    2316.28 |
    | 27760069 |        1569 | 1410622800 |             807.558 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |    1583.72 |
    | 27760070 |        1569 | 1410623100 |             773.837 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 | 2015-04-23 11:57:39 |   -404.651 | 
.. etc
```

Example of output data grouped by hour

```
+----------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| date_time_n_hr | sum_float_value_1  | sum_flaot_value_2    |
+----------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|     1410591600 |  395.3488349914551 |    286.0465211868286 |
|     1410595200 | 3172.6744232177734 |    1988.371980190277 |
|     1410598800 |  4523.837203979492 |   3941.8605613708496 |
|     1410602400 |  4826.162811279297 |  -2225.5813941955566 |
|     1410606000 | 6233.7208251953125 |   209.30242156982422 |
|     1410609600 | 4894.7674560546875 |   -34.88380432128906 |
|     1410613200 | 3316.8604736328125 |   -969.7673645019531 |
|     1410616800 |  4853.488342285156 |    865.1161994934082 |
|     1410620400 |  6665.697814941406 |    544.1861915588379 |
|     1410624000 |  7529.069732666016 |     4102.32551574707 |
|     1410627600 |  3620.930221557617 |   -7981.395439147949 |
|     1410631200 |  979.6511611938477 |   -481.3953628540039 |
|     1410634800 | 205.23256015777588 |   -530.2325592041016 |
|     1410674400 |  8.720930099487305 | -0.45500504970550537 |
|     1410678000 | 1950.0000143051147 |     4723.25577545166 |
|     1410681600 |  9331.976806640625 |     8741.86051940918 |
|     1410685200 |   17227.9072265625 |    7179.069899082184 |
|     1410688800 | 23849.418334960938 |   2183.7211303710938 |
|     1410692400 | 26435.465087890625 |    2762.790672302246 |
|     1410696000 | 27538.953735351562 |    739.5348663330078 |
|     1410699600 |    25251.744140625 |   3920.9302978515625 |
|     1410703200 |  23297.67431640625 |   -7758.139587402344 |
|     1410706800 |  16787.20928955078 |    -10772.0927734375 |
|     1410710400 |  10172.67431640625 |   -3223.255828857422 |
.. etc
```

Comment: Please show an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: This is not a perfect sample data, but I tried to demonstrate in the excel sheet how the output for 15m and hour intervals are aggregated, and how date_time is set  https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhna0fp2svbjugw/example.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Consider placing that data in the question itself. External links are subject to link rot and are less accessible than data posted in the question. You may get better results if your question contains all of the information necessary to provide an answer.

Comment: Fixed, I added example of existing data table, and example of how would a n hour interval group would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping correctly by year, month, day and hour. But what you show is different. What is date_time*12 supposed to represent? First of all, you grab one of the date_times matching the hour randomly. Then you multiply that with 12. Say date_time is March 6, 2015 at 11:00 am. What do you think you get when you multiply that datetime? It simply makes no sense.

A correct query would be for instance:

```
select 
  date_format(date_time,'%Y%m%d %H'),
  sum(float_value_1), 
  sum(float_value_2)
from location_data 
where unique_id = 1616 
group by date_format(date_time,'%Y%m%d %H');
```

If you want quarters of the hour, it gets a little more complicated, because hours, minutes and seconds are measures, but a quarter of an hour is an amount (a quarter) of such a measure (the hour). So we must find out in which quarter of the hour the date_time resides in:

```
select 
  concat(
    date_format(date_time,'%Y%m%d %H'),
    case
      when minute(date_time) between  0 and 14 then 'Q1'
      when minute(date_time) between 15 and 29 then 'Q2'
      when minute(date_time) between 30 and 44 then 'Q3'
      when minute(date_time) between 45 and 59 then 'Q4'
    end
  ) as quarter,
  sum(float_value_1), 
  sum(float_value_2)
from location_data 
where unique_id = 1616 
group by 
  concat(
    date_format(date_time,'%Y%m%d %H'),
    case
      when minute(date_time) between  0 and 14 then 'Q1'
      when minute(date_time) between 15 and 29 then 'Q2'
      when minute(date_time) between 30 and 44 then 'Q3'
      when minute(date_time) between 45 and 59 then 'Q4'
    end
  );
```

Or with a derived table, to avoid the duplicate evaluation of the quarter:

```
select 
  quarter, sum(float_value_1), sum(float_value_2)
from
(
  select 
    location_data.*,
    concat(
      date_format(date_time,'%Y%m%d %H'),
      case
        when minute(date_time) between  0 and 14 then 'Q1'
        when minute(date_time) between 15 and 29 then 'Q2'
        when minute(date_time) between 30 and 44 then 'Q3'
        when minute(date_time) between 45 and 59 then 'Q4'
      end
    ) as quarter
  from location_data 
  where unique_id = 1616 
) as quarters
group by quarter;
```

Comment: Your solution seems exactly what I am looking for, thanks! I agree what I did was totally wrong, I was looking at other SO questions and saw some multiplying date with values, but also made no sense to me as It was not giving me that data I want.